# Nodejs +nowjs + Windows

Tags: node.js, nowjs-sockets

I tried installing nodejs and it works fine, I was able to get it running.
Followed exactly the steps shown here:
http://blog.nowjs.com/running-nowjs-natively-on-windows

Then I tried to install the nowjs and run the multiroomchat_server.js example and got this error:

```
[Error: The specified procedure could not be found.
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\now\bin\proxy.node]
Error: The specified procedure could not be found.
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\now\bin\proxy.node
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:480:11)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
at require (module.js:378:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\now\lib\pr
oxy.js:10:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

I'm running windows 7 64bit, installed the 32bit version of node.js node-v0.8.1-x86.msi.

Anyone got it running?

Comment: You might try an older stable version of Node for Windows. It looks like nowjs hasn't been updated for the latest build of Node (and actually hasn't been updated for 3-6 months on Github).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try newer version of node.

Works on Win 7 x64 with node-v0.8.5-x64